# How can I change the frequency of a scheduled event?

Tags: plugin-development, functions, wp-cron, wpse-plugin

I have declared a scheduled event in a plugin like this :

```
function shedule_email_alerts() {
    if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'send_email_alerts_hook' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'send_email_alerts_hook');
    }
}
```

Then i wanted to change the frequency to 'daily', by doing so, replacing the original function with :

```
function shedule_email_alerts() {
    if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'send_email_alerts_hook' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'send_email_alerts_hook');
    }
}
```

But it seems that my event is still fired every hour. I use the [Core control plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/core-control/) to monitor CRON tasks and it still shows as 'once per hour'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I could solve the problem by using `wp_clear_scheduled_hook()`

I commented out my schedule declaration and added `wp_clear_scheduled_hook('send_email_alerts_hook')` at the end. Then deactivate - reactivate my plugin, which removed my scheduled hook. Then removed `wp_clear_scheduled_hook()` and uncommented my code, now the schedule was set properly.

Answer (score 5):

It looks for me that you are adding this event only when there is no such event 'send_email_alerts_hook' scheduled yet. Try something like this and let me know if it workded.

```
function shedule_email_alerts() {
    if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'send_email_alerts_hook' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'send_email_alerts_hook');
    } else {
        wp_reschedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'send_email_alerts_hook');
    } 
}
```

The thing is that you will "rewrite" this event all the time, so it would be good to deactivate this function when it run first time.

The best solution would be to check how those jobs are gathered and check if this event is already added. If so then check if recurrence is different - if so reschedule. You can find this function in wp-includes/cron.php line ~63

```
function wp_schedule_event( $timestamp, $recurrence, $hook, $args = array()) {
    $crons = _get_cron_array();
    $schedules = wp_get_schedules();

    if ( !isset( $schedules[$recurrence] ) )
        return false;

    $event = (object) array( 'hook' => $hook, 'timestamp' => $timestamp, 'schedule' => $recurrence, 'args' => $args, 'interval' => $schedules[$recurrence]['interval'] );
    $event = apply_filters('schedule_event', $event);

    // A plugin disallowed this event
    if ( ! $event )
        return false;

    $key = md5(serialize($event->args));

    $crons[$event->timestamp][$event->hook][$key] = array( 'schedule' => $event->schedule, 'args' => $event->args, 'interval' => $event->interval );
    uksort( $crons, "strnatcasecmp" );
    _set_cron_array( $crons );
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try debuggin with this Plugin i wrote: [Link to Github/Gist](https://gist.github.com/987128). It's a little hack-ish, but it serves its purpose.

*Note that the `wp_footer()` hook must be present in your theme. Else you'll have to hook it somewhere else.*

Comment: Did you know about the [WP-Crontrol](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-crontrol/) and [Cron View](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cron-view/) plugins?

Comment: No, I didn't know.